# EF6, Circular dependency givs DbPpdateException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, circular-dependency

I'm using Entity Framwork 6, code first.

I have an entity **Team** that has a list of **Members** where one **Member** is the **team leader**.

```
public class Team
{
    public virtual List<Member> Members { get; private set; }
    public virtual Member TeamLeader { get; private set; }

    public Team()
    {
        Members = new List<Member>();
    }

    public AddMember(Member member)
    {
        Members.Add(member);
    }

    public AddTeamLeader(Member teamLeader)
    {
        TeamLeader = teamLeader;
        AddMember(teamLeader);
    }
}
```

I want to do the following but it throws DbUpdateException.

```
using(var uow = new UnitOfWork((new DataContext())))
{
    var team = new Team();
    team.AddMember(new Member("Adam"));
    team.AddTeamLeader(new Member("David"));

    uow.Teams.Add(team);
    uow.Complete();
}
```

This works but its not nice and some day someone will write the first version..

```
using(var uow = new UnitOfWork((new DataContext())))
{
    var theTeamLeader = new Member("David");
    uow.Members.Add(theTeamLeader);
    uow.Complete();

    var team = new Team();
    team.AddMember(new Member("Adam"));
    team.AddTeamLeader(theTeamLeader);

    uow.Teams.Add(team);
    uow.Complete();
}
```

Is it possible to create a complete team with members and a leader and save that to the database with only one SaveChanges?

The member table will have a foreign key to the Team table and the Team table will have a foreign key to the member table so it's a circular dependency and therefore I get an DbUpdateException.